# Strange behavior of recursion in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, recursion

I have a simple function in python:

```
def fun(num):
     if num ==0:
       return 0
     if num==1 or num==2:
       return 1
   return fun(num-1) + fun(num-2)
```

And I call it like this: `print fun(10)`. I expect to receive a sequence of the numbers, but instead I get the sum of those numbers. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect anything *other* than the sum of the numbers?

Comment: of course you're getting the sum, look at what you're returning (a value + another value).

Comment: `+` means addition...

Comment: what did you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments suggest your function produces a value as opposed to list (i.e. sequence of numbers).  Reading into your question, it looks like your are trying to generate a fibonacci sequence.  The function below would produce the nth term in the sequence, and the list comprehension (in the final print statement) will produce your desired sequence of numbers.

```
In [18]:

def fib(Nth_Term):
    if Nth_Term == 0:
        return 0
    elif Nth_Term == 1 or Nth_Term == 2:
        return 1
    return fib(Nth_Term - 1) + fib(Nth_Term - 2)

print fib(0)
print fib(1)
print fib(2)
print fib(3)
print fib(10)
print [fib(num) for num in range(0, 11)]
0
1
1
2
55
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Comment: I just imagined a cartoon paper clip saying "it looks like you're trying to generate a fibonacci sequence"

Answer (score 0):

I thought you meant to concatenate them as a string. You need to convert your numbers in strings with str(number) first to do that. But even so, that function makes no sense... Here's what your function does:

```
fun(5)  
=fun(4)+fun(3)  
=fun(3)+fun(2)+fun(2)+fun(1)  
=fun(2)+fun(1)+1+1+1  
=1+1+1+1+1

fun(6)  
=fun(5)+fun(4)  
=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
```

So in the end, it only adds up a bunch of ones together. Something tells me that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you want to do is:

```
def fib_list(n):
  if(n == 0):
    return [1]
  if(n == 1):
    return [1,1]
  f = fib_list(n-1)
  f = f + [f[-1] + f[-2]]
  return f

print fib_list(10)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```